# Simplify a TikZ code

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to simplify this code, obtaining the same `tikzpicture`?

(*Simplify*: I mean reduce code length, e.g., add more `\begin{scope}...\end{scope}`, …)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[thick, blue]
\draw (-6,0.5) to[out=80,in=310,looseness=1] (-4.5,3);
\draw (-4.5,3) to[out=140,in=160,looseness=1] (-3,4);
\draw (-3,4) to[out=-30,in=160] (-1,3);
\draw (-1,3) to[out=-20,in=100] (0,2);
\draw (-1,0.5) to[out=15,in=-90,looseness=1] (0,2);
\draw (-2,0.75) to[out=-10,in=190] (-1,0.5);
\draw (-6,0.5) to[out=270,in=190,looseness=1.5] (-5,0);
\draw (-5,0) to[out=10,in=170,looseness=1.5] (-2,0.75);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[very thin, dashed]

%Per lo spazio topologico V

\draw (-5.5,0.05) -- (-5.5,1.2);
\draw (-5,0.2) -- (-5,1.65);
\draw (-4.5,0.3) -- (-4.5,2);
\draw (-4,0.5) -- (-4,3.75);
\draw (-3.5,0.7) -- (-3.5,3.95);
\draw (-3,0.9) -- (-3,3.9);
\draw (-2.5,0.9) -- (-2.5,3.6);
\draw (-2,0.85) -- (-2,3.35);
\draw (-1.5,0.7) -- (-1.5,3.1);
\draw (-1,0.65) -- (-1,2.9);
\draw (-0.5,0.85) -- (-0.5,2.65);

\draw (-5.75,0.5) -- (-4,0.5);
\draw (-5.5,1) -- (-.5,1);
\draw (-5,1.5) -- (-0.25,1.5);
\draw (-4.5,2) -- (-0.25,2);
\draw (-4.25,2.5) -- (-.3,2.5);
\draw (-4.25,3) -- (-1.25,3);
\draw (-4.25,3.5) -- (-2.5,3.5);

%Per lo spazio topologico U

\draw (2.5,3.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (2.5,2.25);
\draw (2.5,2.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (2.5,1.25);
\draw (2.5,1.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (2.5,0.75);
\draw (3,3.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (3,2.25);
\draw (3,2.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (3,1.25);
\draw (3,1.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (3,0.75);
\draw (3.5,3.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (3.5,2.25);
\draw (3.5,2.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (3.5,1.25);
\draw (3.5,1.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (3.5,0.75);
\draw (4,3.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (4,2.25);
\draw (4,2.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (4,1.25);
\draw (4,1.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (4,0.75);
\draw (4.5,3.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (4.5,2.25);
\draw (4.5,2.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (4.5,1.25);
\draw (4.5,1.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (4.5,0.75);
\draw (5,3.5) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5,3.25);
\draw (5,3.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5,2.25);
\draw (5,2.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5,1.25);
\draw (5,1.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5,0.75);
\draw (5,0.75) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5,0.5);
\draw (5.5,3.5) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5.5,3.25);
\draw (5.5,3.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5.5,2.25);
\draw (5.5,2.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5.5,1.25);
\draw (5.5,1.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5.5,0.75);
\draw (5.5,0.75) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (5.5,0.5);
%\draw (6,3.50) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (6,3.25);
\draw (6,3.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (6,2.25);
\draw (6,2.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (6,1.25);
\draw (6,1.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (6,0.75);
\draw (6,0.75) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (6,0.5);
%\draw (6.5,2.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (6.5,1.25);
%\draw (6.5,1.25) to[out=280,in=80,looseness=1.5] (6.5,0.75);

\draw (2.5,2.75) to[out=45,in=135,looseness=0.5] (6,2.75);
\draw (2.5,2.25) to[out=45,in=135,looseness=0.5] (6,2.25);
\draw (2.5,1.75) to[out=45,in=135,looseness=0.5] (6,1.75);
\draw (2.5,1.25) to[out=45,in=135,looseness=0.5] (6,1.25);
\draw (2.5,0.75) to[out=45,in=135,looseness=0.5] (6,0.75);

\end{scope}

\node at (-5.5,2.5) {\textcolor{blue}{\Huge{\ensuremath V}}};
\draw[thick,dashed,-latex,shorten >= 3pt] (-2,3.5) to[out=15,in=155] (2.5,3.25); \node at (0.75,4.15) {\Large{$\Lambda_p$}};
\node at (7.25,2.5) {\textcolor{red}{\Huge{\ensuremath U}}};

\draw[thick,red] (2,1) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=1.8] (4.5,3.5);
\draw[thick,red] (4.5,3.5) to[out=45,in=90,looseness=1.25] (6.5,2.5);
%\draw[thick,red] (6.5,2.5) to[out=-45,in=100,looseness=1] (7.5,1.5);
%\draw[thick,red] (6.5,2.5) to[out=-45,in=10,looseness=1.5] (6.5,0);
%\draw[thick,red] (4.5,0.5) to[out=-10,in=170,looseness=2] (6.5,0);
\draw[thick,red] (6.5,2.5) to[out=-90,in=-20,looseness=1.75] (4.5,0.5);
%\draw[thick,red] (2,1) to[out=-60,in=160,looseness=2] (4.5,0.5);
%\draw[thick,red] (2.5,3.5) to[out=190,in=190,looseness=2] (4.5,0.5);
\draw[thick,red] (2,1) to[out=-75,in=170,looseness=1] (4.5,0.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For instance `\color{blue}\Huge$V$` would be a first step, because `\textcolor{blue}{\Huge{\ensuremath V}}` is really bad coding under many respects. Of course, `\node[font=\Huge,blue] at (-5.5,2.5) {$V$};` would be an even simpler way.

Comment: Be careful what you wish for. I'd argue the approach taken [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191342/77083) meets your criteria for "simplify" but arguably isn't a way to simplify code.

Comment: Your question is a legal, a good one. Could you describe the mathematical context of your figure?

Comment: I'm creating many figures like this because I'm writing a Book on Topological Spaces and Differential Manifolds.

Comment: @Puck What exactly does the figure illustrate for? From that, maybe we have a better way of drawing

Comment: @BlackMild: Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an immersed differential surface, given $p \in S$, the function $\Lambda_p:V\to U$ is a coordinate chart around $p$, where $V$ is an open domine in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U$ is an open codomine in $S$. In this figure I represented an Atlas, i.e., a couple $\mathfrak{A}\left(S,\Lambda_p\right)$, where $\Lambda_p$ is in particular a Homeomorphism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following isn't exactly the same: The grids inside your topologies are touching the borders (if you don't want this you can replace `blue` with `white, double=blue` and `red` with `white, double=red` to get a bit of distance in a way, the brilliant idea wasn't mine, all praise to [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644299/simplify-a-tikz-picture/644313?noredirect=1#comment1605660_644313)), and the `$\Lambda_p$` moved a bit to the left.

This makes use of saving paths (only necessary to have the border of the topology cover the dashed lines of the grid), the `clip` option, combines multiple `\draw` instructions into single paths, uses `\foreach` for the squiggly grid, and `grid` for the rectangular grid, places the `$\Lambda_p$` node automatically in the centre of the arrow-path, combines the `$U$` and `$V$` on the same path to only need `font=\Huge` once, and maybe a few other small changes. Oh, and I removed unrelated packages from the preamble and used `standalone`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[font=\Huge]
    (-5.5,  2.5) node[blue] {$V$}
    ( 7.25, 2.5) node[red]  {$U$};

  \path[save path=\pathV]
    (-6, 0.5) to[out= 80, in=310]                (-4.5, 3)
              to[out=140, in=160]                (-3,   4)
              to[out=-30, in=160]                (-1,   3)
              to[out=-20, in=100]                ( 0,   2)
              to[out=-90, in= 15]                (-1,   0.5)
              to[out=190, in=-10]                (-2,   0.75)
              to[out=170, in= 10, looseness=1.5] (-5,   0)
              to[out=190, in=270, looseness=1.5] (-6,   0.5);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip[use path=\pathV];
    \draw[very thin, dashed, step=0.5] (-6, 0) grid (0, 4);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[thick, blue, use path=\pathV];

  \path[save path=\pathU]
    (2, 1) to[out= 90, in=180, looseness=1.8]  (4.5, 3.5)
           to[out= 45, in= 90, looseness=1.25] (6.5, 2.5)
           to[out=-90, in=-20, looseness=1.75] (4.5, 0.5)
           to[out=170, in=-75]                 (2,   1);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip[use path=\pathU];
    \draw[very thin, dashed, out=280, in=80, looseness=1.5]
      \foreach\x in{2, 2.5, ..., 6}
        {
          (\x, 4) to (\x, 3.5)
                  to (\x, 3.25)
                  to (\x, 2.25)
                  to (\x, 1.25)
                  to (\x, 0.75)
                  to (\x, 0.25)
        }
      \foreach\y in{3.25, 2.75, ..., 0.25}
        {(2, \y) to[out=45, in=135, looseness=0.5] (6.5, \y)};
  \end{scope}
  \draw[thick, red, use path=\pathU];

  \draw[thick, dashed, -latex, shorten >= 3pt]
    (-2,   3.5)
      to[out=15, in=155] node[above, font=\Large]{$\Lambda_p$}
    ( 2.5, 3.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Comparison

New output:

[image]

Your original output:

[image]

#### Code size

##### Lines (without empty lines)

- Yours: 86, or 76 (additionally without commented lines)
- Mine: 47

##### Characters (without spaces and newlines)

- Yours: 3381
- Mine: 1198 (number outdated because also the `looseness=1` was removed, thanks [Black Mild](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644299/simplify-a-tikz-code/644313?noredirect=1#comment1605772_644313))

Comment: Nice. (+1) You could make it even shorter using `\path[save path=\pathV]plot[smooth cycle, tension=.8] coordinates{(-6, 0.5)(-4.5, 3)(-3,4)(-1,3)( 0,2)(-1,0.5)(-2,0.75)(-5,0)};` Of course that changes the curve somewhat.

Comment: You could (sort of) add space between the grid and the border with a double line, e.g. `\draw[white, double=red, line width=1mm, use path=\pathU];`

Comment: @SandyG the goal wasn't really golfing :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that's a good idea.

Comment: `looseness=1` can be removed

Comment: @BlackMild oh, you're right, that's the initial value.